# how to change cells color per value next to it

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following set of 2 columns and n rows:

```
 A       B
1 44000 44000
2 2800  2730
3 17000 21160
4 1000  1046
5 700       0
6 1500  1249
7 300       107
8 1200  400
9 0     1400
10 4500 3582
11 0        280
```

I would like to create a Conditional Formatting rule for column B, so if value in any row exceeds the associated value in row A the cell becomes red: https://gyazo.com/83a45768c6952f5590448700059179ce

The problem with this approach is I have to modify every single cell and cannot apply the whole Rule for all cells in column B.

If I apply this rule to the set of cells in col A I receive: `This type of reference cannot be used in Conditional Formatting formula`: http://prntscr.com/feo3c0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula:

```
=$B1>$A1
```

The Applies to:

```
=$B:$B
```

[image]